# show success page if form is successfully submitted

Tags: angularjs

How do i track if a upload is success and redirect to a certain page using angular and ng-file upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Currently it uploads the file but i need to show an error if the form is failed to insert to mysql or show the success page

Below is my angular function

```
Upload.upload({
    url: 'api/upload-image.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    file: file,
    data: {
        'awesomeThings': $scope.awesomeThings,
        'targetPath' : '/media/'
    }
})
```

in my php code

```
$status = $this->Upload_tools->add($data);
```

If an upload is access status will return `true` or else `false`

if `success` i want to show this page

```
         $location.path('/show/'+qid);
```

Comment: See examples on how to work with promise callback

Comment: The Angular $http service rejects when the server returns HTTP status outside the range 200-299. Return status 200 OK or 5xx Server Error. On the client side use standard promise `.then` and `.catch` methods.

Answer (score 0):

See example code in ng-file-upload read.me:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    }).then(function (resp) {

        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
```

Now, your code will be something like this:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/upload-image.php', 
        method: 'POST',
        file: file,
        data: {
            'awesomeThings': $scope.awesomeThings,
            'targetPath' : '/media/'
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        //Success case code
        $location.path('/show/'+qid);
    }, function (resp) {
        //Error case code
    }, function (evt) {
        //progress calculation
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
```